# Refreshing data in Watch App from App Group cached on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

To pass data from my IOS App to my Watch app, I am caching the data into NSUserDefaults (in an App Group) in my iOS AppDelegate. (I call this method both in didFinishLaunching and willTerminate.)

I then pass this data to my Watch app via the App Group and all works well.

The problem is that when I change the data on my iPhone app I want to update the data on my Watch App as well, but it is not updated unless I uninstall and reinstall the Watch App.

I have tried my fetch from App Groups method in both awakeWithContext and willActivate but the data is still stale.  How can I refresh the data on the Watch short of uninstalling/reinstalling?

*edit: In other words, the Apple Watch app apparently keeps running on the watch... whereas I would prefer that it was killed, so that when the user changes data on the iPhone app, then taps on the watch app it opens with the new data, instead of just awaking with the stale data.

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    var nameList: [String]?
    var currentUserName: String?

    var peopleDict: [String : [String : [String : String]]]?


    @IBOutlet weak var personTable: WKInterfaceTable!

    private func loadTableData() {

        if let list = nameList {

            personTable.setNumberOfRows(list.count, withRowType: "PersonTableRowController")

            for (index, personName) in enumerate(list) {
                if let row = personTable.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as? PersonTableRowController {
                    row.personLabel.setText(personName)

                } else { println("Could not cast as PersonTableRowController") }
            }
        }

    }


    func fetchFromAppGroup() {

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.myndarc.thredz2")
        defaults?.synchronize()
        if let fetchedPeopleDict: AnyObject = defaults?.valueForKey("peopleDict") {


            //save peopleDict locally
            peopleDict = fetchedPeopleDict as? [String : [String : [String : String]]]


            if let dict = fetchedPeopleDict as? NSDictionary {
                nameList = dict.allKeys as? [String]
            }

        }
            if let user: AnyObject = defaults?.valueForKey("currentUser") {

                currentUserName = user as? String



        }
    }


    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)



    }

    override func willActivate() {

        super.willActivate()
        fetchFromAppGroup()

        loadTableData()


    }
```